# Why isn't a stubbed sftp Camel endpoint respecting the "include" option in this test?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, apache-camel, junit5

I am trying to stub an sftp consumer endpoint for testing purposes - I don't want to try spinning up a container just yet. Here is what I've got so far:

```
import org.apache.camel.*;
import org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWith;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition;
import org.apache.camel.test.spring.junit5.CamelSpringBootTest;
import org.apache.camel.test.spring.junit5.MockEndpointsAndSkip;
import org.apache.camel.test.spring.junit5.UseAdviceWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;


import java.io.File;
import static com.routes.zipping.Resources.*;

/**
 * Tests a from() route, the scheme of which is not "direct", but is "sftp".
 */

@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest(properties = "camel.springboot.java-routes-include-pattern=**/GetWretchedBillImagesRoute*")
@MockEndpointsAndSkip("direct:split")
@UseAdviceWith
public class ITGetWretchedBIllImagesRoute {

    @Produce
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Autowired
    CamelContext camelContext;

    @EndpointInject("mock:direct:split")
    MockEndpoint mockConvert;

    private String stubUrl;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("ZIPs are count")
    @DirtiesContext
    @Disabled("This gives back inconsistent results or seems to ignore the 'include' file option, so zip of any name or even a pdf is received at mocked endpoint.")
    void testGetFile_ZipMessageCountsButNotPdf() throws Exception {
        File zip = new File(TEST_PATH + ZIP + IN + "zipWith3Files.zip");
        assertTrue(zip.exists(), "The required test resource file is unavailable");

        File pdf = new File(TEST_PATH + PDF + IN + "myPdf.pdf");
        assertTrue(pdf.exists(), "The required test resource file is unavailable");

        AdviceWith.adviceWith(camelContext, "Wretched Bill Image ZIP Poller", routeBuilder -> {
            RouteDefinition rd = routeBuilder.getOriginalRoute();
            rd.setAutoStartup("true");
            var originalUrl = rd.getEndpointUrl();
            System.out.println("Advicing " + originalUrl);
            stubUrl = "stub:" + originalUrl;
            routeBuilder.replaceFromWith(stubUrl);
        });

        camelContext.start();

        mockConvert.expectedMessageCount(0);

        producerTemplate.sendBody(stubUrl, zip);
        producerTemplate.sendBody(stubUrl, zip);
        producerTemplate.sendBody(stubUrl, pdf);
        producerTemplate.sendBody(stubUrl, pdf);

        mockConvert.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

And here is the original route:

```
import com.routes.client.props.WretchedRouteProps;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class GetWretchedBillImagesRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    public static String ROUTE_ID = "Wretched Bill Image ZIP Poller";

    private final WretchedRouteProps arp;

    @Autowired
    public GetWretchedBillImagesRoute(WretchedRouteProps wretchedRouteProps) {
        this.arp = wretchedRouteProps;
    }

    //@formatter:off
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(getSftpStartEndpoint())
                .log("Polled for zipped image files for Wretched")
                .id("Wretched Bill Image ZIP Poller")
                .routeId("Wretched Bill Image ZIP Poller")
                .setHeader("unzipTo", constant(arp.getFileDestination()))
                .setHeader("nameMatters", constant(arp.nameMatters()))
                .setHeader("client", constant("Wretched"))
                .autoStartup(arp.isAutoStart() || arp.shouldAutoStartThisRoute())
                .to("direct:split");
    }
    //@formatter:on

    private String getSftpStartEndpoint() {
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append("sftp://").append(arp.getSftpUser()).append("@").append(arp.getSftpHost()).append("/")
                .append(arp.getSftpPath())
                .append("?password=").append(arp.getSftpPassword())
                .append("&scheduler=spring&scheduler.cron=").append(arp.getRouteSchedule())
                .append("&readLock=changed&readLockMinAge=300000")
                .append("&streamDownload=true&stepwise=false")
                .append("&timeUnit=MINUTES")
                .append("&noop=").append(arp.shouldMoveFromFtp())
                .append("&move=").append(arp.getArchiveDestination())
                .append("&include=").append(arp.getWretchedBillZipRegex())
                .toString();
    }
}
```

I notice that this will pass with multiple expectations:

`mockConvert.expectedMessageCount(0);`
`mockConvert.expectedMessageCount(4);`

It will only fail if I expect more messages than I produce, e.g.,

`mockConvert.expectedMessageCount(5);`

So 1) why aren't the stubbed options ruling out **all** of the files I'm sending through the producer, given the mismatch in the "include" regex, and 2) why do multiple expectations pass? As an aside, if there is a better way to test an existing sftp consumer endpoint without a test container, please do let me know or point me somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only really know the answer to your second question:

##### 2

`MockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(i)` only ensures that `i` messages were received. It considers the expectation to be fulfilled as-soon-as the message count has been reached. Any extraneous messages are not considered. A quick look at the [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-mock/latest/org/apache/camel/component/mock/MockEndpoint.html#expectedMessageCount-int-) states that you could use `setAssertPeriod(l)` to enforce that expected message count is true even after that period. The reason why 5 then doesn't pass is that the endpoint never received a fifth message.